# Extending a convex function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, convex-analysis

Suppose $f:(a,b) \to \mathbb R$ is twice differentiable with the property that $c_1 \leq f''(x) \leq c_2$ for every $x \in (a,b)$, where $c_1, c_2$ are positive constants. Is it possible to extend $f$ to all of $\mathbb R$ such that this property holds? Is there a general procedure for this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one possibility: $$\begin{cases} \alpha_1x^2+\alpha_2x+\alpha_3 & x\le a\\f(x) & a<x<b \\ \beta_1x^2+\beta_2x+\beta_3 & x\ge b\end{cases}$$

You choose $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3$ so that the function and its first two derivatives agree at $a$ (on both sides).  Similarly, you choose $\beta_1, \beta_2, \beta_3$ so that the function and its first two derivatives agree at $b$.

This new function has constant second derivative on all of $(-\infty,a]$, and also on $[b,+\infty)$. Hence it satisfies the desired bound.

Comment: Thank you very much for this beautiful answer.